# To_Date function always returns null

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a string formatted column which I get via:

```
session.sql("select milestoneactualdate from dba")
```

This column contans data like "20190101". I want to cast this string to date via:

```
session.sql("select *, to_date(milestoneactualdate, '%YYYY%MM%DD') as datetest from dba").show()
```

I also tried:

```
changedTypedf = df.withColumn("milestoneactualdate", to_date(df["milestoneactualdate"], '%YYYY%MM%DD').cast('Date'))
```

But it always returns "null". Why is my cast function not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your date format needs to be `yyyyMMdd`, see [Date Format Pattern Syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html#datepattern).

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([['20190101']], ['milestoneactualdate'])
df.show()
+-------------------+
|milestoneactualdate|
+-------------------+
|           20190101|
+-------------------+

df.selectExpr('to_date(milestoneactualdate, "yyyyMMdd") as date').show()
+----------+
|      date|
+----------+
|2019-01-01|
+----------+
```

Comment: I was overlooking this for 4 days, thanks alot for this clean answer & the clean question!